# Convert from BSTR to char*

Tags: c++, com, type-conversion

I have seen:

1. [Convert BSTR to CHAR* and CHAR* to BSTR in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508982/convert-bstr-to-char-and-char-to-bstr-in-c)
2. [Problems converting BSTR to char *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14443193/problems-converting-bstr-to-char)
3. [Convert BSTR to char*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648848/convert-bstr-to-char)

using these question I am attempting to convert a `BSTR` to a `char*` via

```
#include "comutil.h"
STDMETHODIMP CServer::Initialise(BSTR strCmdFilePath, 
   VARIANT_BOOL bDiagErr, VARIANT_BOOL bProcErr, BSTR* RESULT)
{
   char *p = _com_util::ConvertBSTRToString(strCmdFilePath);
   ...
}
```

but I am getting:

> Error  1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "char * __stdcall _com_util::ConvertBSTRToString(wchar_t *)" (?ConvertBSTRToString@_com_util@@YGPADPA_W@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual long __stdcall CServer::Initialise(wchar_t *,short,short,wchar_t * *)" (?Initialise@CServer@@UAGJPA_WFFPAPA_W@Z)

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302364/convert-bstr-to-const-char)

Comment: I have seen that answer too. This does not explain why I am getting the error above...

Comment: It appears you haven't linked the com support library, and depending on the version of visual studio you're building with (which you should include in your question), you may be experiencing a bug in the pragma comments for pulling in the right lib. If so, it is correctable , but first: Out of curiosity, does the same problem happen for both debug *and* release builds ?

Comment: Working VS2013 and yes this also occurs for the Release build as well as the Debug build.

Comment: Ok, lastly, are you building with `wchar_t` as a native type? I ask because I ran into a similar problem. [This may help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dh8che7s.aspx).

Comment: ... or `comsuppwd.lib` for debug builds. @HansPassant yeah, I had a similar issue with VS2010 a couple years back. Was a little surprised it wasn't handled automatically by the pragmas.

Comment: @HansPassant that was the answer. If you want to write that I will accept...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your project is not linking the required library.  Which is `comsuppw.lib` for the Release build, `comsuppwd.lib` for the Debug build.  Do note that you can always see the required library in [the MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewezf1f6.aspx).  It is annotated at the bottom of the article.  "Header" tells you what you need to #include, "Lib" tells you what you need to link.

There's an easier way for this library, the best way to get the linker instruction embedded so it is automatic is by #including the .h file that contains the #pragma comment.  Fix:

```
#include <comdef.h>     // Added
#include <comutil.h>
```